# Getting access to globals in DialogFragment static class

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I've followed Google docs and created an inner class to popup a dialog in my android app.

I've been running it fine in eclipse for a while, unbeknownst to me there was an error that came up when I imported the app into android studio to start using the stable release. I was getting the "Fragment inner class should be static" error upon trying to build.

OK so I understand now after researching that this is a bad thing, but when I change it to static, I now have a bunch of references to (a) global variables , and (b) "MainActivity.class" , that are now errors.

So inside this DialogFragment inner class, how do I access my globals, or pass them in, and how do I reference MainActivity.class ?

Eg:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);


for (NewsEvent ne : filteredList) { //filteredList is global List of objects
    ...
```

I am calling the dialog in the onOptionsItemSelected like this:

```
AlertDialogFragment alert = new AlertDialogFragment();
alert.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "Alerts");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a `Data` to the DialogFragment use `static newInstance(params)` method.
Put the `Data` in a `Intent` and on the `onCreate()` method get your `Data` from the `Intent`.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog) example from the Android dev